# Using Ctrl-Tab to switch between tabs in Mac Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch between tabs in Terminal.app on a Mac (OS 10.4 and 10.5 specifically)?  This is how I switch tabs in Firefox and Aquamacs, and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> is too awkward to me.  I am aware of this related question:

[How can I change the keyboard shortcut for switching tabs in Mac Terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/176177/unable-to-efficiently-switch-tabs-in-mac-terminal)

And hence the Keyboard Shortcuts section of the System Preferences, but the dialog box for Keyboard Shortcuts doesn't seem to accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the Keyboard Shortcut field.  Is there a special keyboard sequence for inputting tabs (with modifiers) into a dialog box field on a Mac?  Is there any other method that would allow me to customize Terminal.app in the way I desire?

Comment: Just for reference: Shift-Command-Left/Right Arrow also switch tabs. And in Mac OS X Lion 10.7, you can use a three-finger swipe to switch tabs

Answer (score 128):

I just tried this under Snow Leopard and it worked beautifully:

1. Open System Preferences => Keyboard
2. Go to Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Click on "Application Shortcuts" on the left
4. Click the little "+" to add a program
5. Navigate to Terminal (it's hidden in Applications/Utilities)
6. For the Menu Title type "Show Next Tab" or "Show Previous Tab" ("Select Next Tab" and "Select Previous Tab" for Mavericks or older) (Also, these items will be different for languages other than English.)
7. For the Keyboard Shortcut type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>
8. Click Add. You are g2g!

Comment: You++, Works on mountain lion too.

Comment: Cool, same to mavericks.

Comment: It's "Show Next Tab" and "Show Previous Tab" under Yosemite. But it's slower than using Command+Shift+Right or Command+Shift+Left for some reason (which, btw, makes me envy Linux users).

Comment: Not working for Yosemite :(

Comment: @Siddharth It works in Yosemite for me, using the tips from LoremIpsum above. And it's not slow at all btw.

Comment: @knatten thanks for the information. It seems that they have recently fixed it. I checked it now and it works for me too :)

Comment: This is a game changer for Mac users, thank you!

Comment: In OSX El Capitan I don't see a way to navigate to Terminal inside the utilities folder to add it to the application shortcuts list. I wound up just moving the app into /Applications, which worked.

Comment: Still works on El Capitan!  :-)

Comment: On El Capitan you need to use "**Select Next Tab**" and "**Select Previous Tab**" for the menu title

Answer (score 20):

1. Select next (right) tab <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>
2. Select previous (left) tab <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

So you would need to do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> for left and right respectively.

Comment: Why did Apple decide to assign such horrid shortcuts to such frequently needed commands?

Answer (score 7):

Yet an addition to the [answer above](https://superuser.com/questions/26100/using-ctrl-tab-to-switch-between-tabs-in-mac-terminal-app/54004#54004):
The manual binding of shortcuts has changed in Yosemite from "Select Next Tab" & "Select Previous Tab" to "**Show** Next Tab" & "**Show** Previous Tab"

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>arrow left/right</kbd> works out of the box on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here is the only way I could figure out how to do it. First create the command you want to use system preferences but use a placeholder instead of tab since it wont let you insert the tab.  Then open up com.apple.terminal.plist (most easily done with the plist editor) and go to the section  NSUserKeyEquivalents and you should see the commands you created.  Delete the placeholder and go to the edit menu and select special characters.  The tab character is in the arrows section. It's an arrow pointing towards a vertical line. Its unicode value is 21E5.  Once that is inserted save and quit and it should work!  You could also do all of this in system preferences but you have to insert all the characters instead of typing them and I have no idea what their unicode values are.

By the way, I assume apple has at least a semi good reason for not allowing tab characters normally, so proceed with caution. A lot of global shortcuts use tab but ctrl-tab doesn't seem to be one of them so you're probably okay.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home). It is a terminal alternative that supports this keyboard shortcut out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

For yosemite: http://taiki.net/2014/11/osx-terminal-sck.html

As I do not have any reputation to just comment I had to copy the answer.

1. Open System Preferences => Keyboard
2. Go to Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Click on "Application Shortcuts" on the left
4. Click the little "+" to add a program
5. Navigate to Terminal (it's hidden in Applications/Utilities)
6. For the Menu Title type "Show Next Tab" or "Show Previous Tab" (these items will be different for languages other than English)
7. For the Keyboard Shortcut type Ctrl-Tab or Ctrl-Shift-Tab

The difference with yosemite is... they changed from "Select X Tab" to "Show X Tab"...

Why?